# Help with String parsing

Tags: c#

I am trying to parse the string and see if the value after ":" is Integer. If it is not integer then remove "Test:M" from string.

Here is the example string I have.

```
string testString = "Test:34,Test:M";
```

The result I need `testString = "Test:34"`

```
string[] data = testString.Split(',');
for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
{
    string[] data1 = data[i].Split(':');
    int num = 0;
    if(Int32.TryParse(data1[1], out num))
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give more examples of expected input and the expected output?

Comment: Why don't you implement the reverse logic? If the the value is an integer, then you append it to the result string.

Comment: @Alexandre: Exactly what I proposed. Modifying a `string` is going to be slow as the `string` gets large. Using a `StringBuilder` will end up being faster in the end.

Comment: You don't need to initialize `num` because it's guaranteed to be intialized as an `out` parameter.

Comment: Its much easier to pull out what you want and put it in a new string, then modify the existing screen (which in the background is really building a new string usually) to get the result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could continue on with the looping structure but I, personally, like the look of LINQ a little better:

```
var dummy = 0;

var intStrings =
    testString.Split(',')
        .Where(s => s.Contains(":") && int.TryParse(s.Split(':')[1], out dummy))
        .ToArray();

var result = String.Join(",", intStrings);
```

Comment: @Groo - What else am I missing?

Comment: I believe an `out` keyword. Also, the dummy `outVar` might be pulled out of the lambda, but that's no error, just a way to simplify the lambda's body.

Comment: Nice answer. Just got edit privilege so I thought I'd try it out on this to help avoid an IndexOutOfRangeException!

Answer (score 5):

You're almost there. Try using this:

```
    var builder = new StringBuilder();
    string[] data = testString.Split(',');
    for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
    {
        string[] data1 = data[i].Split(':');
        int num = 0;
        if(Int32.TryParse(data1[1], out num))
        {
            builder.Append(data[i]);
            buidler.Append(',');
        }
    }

    testString = builder.ToString();
```

**EDIT**: Adding the `","` to keep the comma in the output...

**EDIT**: Taking @Groo suggestion on avoiding implicit string concatenation.

Comment: You probably need to add in the commas, too.

Comment: Since you are using a `StringBuilder`, you might also write `builder.Append(',');` in a separate line, to avoid unnecessary concatenations. Also, there will be a comma at the end of the resulting string, so a `String.Join` might be a better solution altogether.

Answer (score 2):

You could just build a new collection with the desired values...

```
string testString = "Test:34,Test:M, 23:test";

int temp = default( int );

var integerLines =  from line in testString.Split( ',' )
                    let value = line.Split( ':' ).ElementAt( 1 )
                    let isInteger = Int32.TryParse( value, out temp )
                    where isInteger
                    select line;
```

Comment: @Groo I wasn't aware that was a constraint in the OPs problem domain, but I updated example anyway.

Answer (score 1):

```
        string testString = "Test:34,Test:M,Crocoduck:55";
        string[] data = testString.Split(',');
        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
        {
            string s = data[i].Remove(0, data[i].IndexOf(':') + 1);
            int num;
            if (Int32.TryParse(s, out num))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(num);
            }
        }
```

Comment: I believe the OP wants to keep the string data as output. Your answer dumps text to the console.

Answer (score 0):

I should warn that don't have coding tool on my hands, so can not provide you with 
clearly compilable code, but in difference others I would suggest to use           Split(string[]), for example: Split(new string[]{",",":"}) and avoid call split 2 times. After this you will get clear view which indexes of the array are integers. In your example it SHOULD be every N*3. You need to test it, by the way.

Hope this helps.

Regards.